# Extract value from JSON with key name includes # in bigquery

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a table called test in bigquery. It has one column called `attributes`.
The value is in JSON with "# of items" being the key, for example: {"# of items": "100"}

When I executed the query below
`SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(attributes, "$['# of items']") AS num_items
FROM test`

I hit the following error:
`Error: JSONPath parse error at: ['# of items']`

what is the easiest way to access its value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It fails for BigQuery Legacy SQL

Use BigQuery Standard SQL instead and you will be fine

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.test` AS (
  SELECT '{"# of items": "100"}' AS attributes
)
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(attributes, "$['# of items']") AS num_items
FROM `project.dataset.test`
```

with result as

```sql
Row num_items    
1   "100"
```

If for some reason you are bound to BQ Legacy SQL - use below trick

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(REPLACE(attributes, '"# of items"', "'number of items'"), "$['number of items']") AS num_items
FROM [project:dataset.test]
```

Comment: sure. please consider voting up the answer

Comment: But the part `SELECT '{"# of items": "100"}'` is hardcoded. What if I want all the values for the key `# of items`? This is not my case but I can get an idea with it

Comment: would you mind posting your question as a separate question - so we will be able to answer it. format of comments does not allow to do so

Comment: btw. whatever you see within WITH statement is just a dummy data here - you can remove that part and actually run that statement against your real table

Comment: I thought  the WITH block was mandatory. I finally got it. Thanks